# Browser tab query "Receiving end does not exist" which works on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Background script

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (event) {
  if( event.type === 'authenticate' ) {
    browser.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tab) {
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {
        method: 'main',
        auth0: "test"
      }, function() {});
    });
  }
});
```

Content script

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage({
  type: "authenticate"
});

browser.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if( request.method == 'main' ) {
    login();
  } else if( request.method == 'logout' ) {
    logout();
  }
  sendResponse({});
});
```

The event goes through and the tab id is correct, but the debug info from firefox shows "Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

On chrome the event callback goes through. Anyone know what the issue is? Looking through google I found something about the id not being correct but I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: You're sending a new message to the active tab, but an instance of the content script runs in each matching tab, not just the active one. Simply respond to the sender directly as shown in the [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) documentation (see examples with sendResponse).

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Comment: `browser.extension.onMessage` [shouldn't even exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension#Events); `chrome.extension.onMessage` is deprecated in Chrome and I doubt Mozilla copied it to the `browser` namespace. Use `browser.runtime.onMessage` instead.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `browser.runtime.onMessage` and changing

```
browser.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tab) {
  browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {
    method: 'main',
    auth0: "test"
  }, function() {});
});
```

to

```
browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {
        method: 'main',
        auth0: "test"
    });
});
```

fixed it for me.